# how to create XML file using visual basic

Tags: xml, vba, visual-studio

i have a question , i want to create an xml file with visual basic in visual studio .

xml file should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root Name="scenario">
  <Entries>
    <Entry Name="firstname" Value="gedaan" />
    <Entry Name="lastname" Value="salame" />
    <Entry Name="job" Value="Engineer" />
  </Entries>
</Root>
```

i searched alot , but found nothing helpful because the xml that i want is little different , there is no somthing like this : `<FirstName>gedaan</FirstName>` ,its just `<Entry Name="FirstName" Value="gedaan" />`

please help 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this before.  You are going to need to print the XML line by line.  Use FileSystemObject to create a blank .xml file.  Then Open the .xml as an output. Next build your .xml string and print it to the output.

```
    Dim fs as Object
    Dim strWriteFileName , strWriteLine as string

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strWriteFileName = Forms!MAIN.OutputFile.value & ".xml"

    Open strWriteFileName For Output As #1
         strWriteLine = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
         Print #1, strWriteLine
         strWriteLine = "<Root Name=""scenario"">"
         Print #1, strWriteLine
         strWriteLine = "<Entries>"
         Print #1, strWriteLine
         'Depending on XML schema here may be a good place for a Loop'
         strWriteLine = "<Entry Name=""firstname"" Value=""gedaan"" />"
         Print #1, strWriteLine
         strWriteLine = "<Entry Name=""lastname"" Value=""salame"" />"
         Print #1, strWriteLine
         strWriteLine = "<Entry Name=""job"" Value=""Engineer"" />"
         Print #1, strWriteLine
         'And here may be a good place to end the loop'
         strWriteLine = "</Entries>"
         Print #1, strWriteLine
         strWriteLine = "</Root>"
         Print #1, strWriteLine
   Close #1
   set fs = Nothing
```

That will print what you have above.  If you need to add multiple entries simply throw a loop in to print more names.  I also used a form called MAIN and a textbox called OutputFile so feel free to replace those with whatever you need.